How can I add a "sub-item" in Jake's Resume in the LaTeX compiler?
I am a complete beginner with LaTeX, but I am trying to help my mother make a resume using the Jake's Resume Overleaf template. Under a singular bullet point in the "Experience" section, I want to add a "sub-item" - basically a further indented bullet point - but I don't know how to do this. I want it to look something like this:
I figure that it has to do with these lines of code:
\resumeSubheading
  {Undergraduate Research Assistant}{June 2020 -- Present}
  {Texas A\&M University}{College Station, TX}
  \resumeItemListStart
    \resumeItem{Developed a REST API using FastAPI and PostgreSQL to store data from learning management systems}
    \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using Flask, React, PostgreSQL and Docker to analyze GitHub data}
    \resumeItem{Explored ways to visualize GitHub collaboration in a classroom setting}
  \resumeItemListEnd

And specifically adding something under here:
\resumeItem{Developed a REST API using FastAPI and PostgreSQL to store data from learning management systems}

But I think I would also have to add some sort of \newcommand line above. How can I achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Insert an itemize environment with the sub-items listed using \item as part of the \resumeItem argument:

\resumeSubheading
  {Undergraduate Research Assistant}{June 2020 -- Present}
  {Texas A\&M University}{College Station, TX}
  \resumeItemListStart
    \resumeItem{Developed a REST API using FastAPI and PostgreSQL to store data from learning management systems
      \begin{itemize}
          \item A sub-item
      \end{itemize}}
    \resumeItem{Developed a full-stack web application using Flask, React, PostgreSQL and Docker to analyze GitHub data
      \begin{itemize}[label=$\circ$]
        \item Another sub-item
      \end{itemize}}
    \resumeItem{Explored ways to visualize GitHub collaboration in a classroom setting}
  \resumeItemListEnd

You can adjust the formatting of the bulleted item by supplying an optional label=<stuff> argument (thanks to the loaded enumitem package.
